# How to execute a .ps1 from another .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, window

I have two PowerShell files. a.ps1 and b.ps1.

At a center point in a.ps1 I want to start executing code in b.ps1 and terminate a.ps1 script.

How to do it considering that both files are located in the same folder?

Comment: at the moment I am using PS 'path file' with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it ok if b.ps1 is executed in a new Power Shell process? If so the following should do what you describe.

```
Invoke-Item (start powershell ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\b.ps1"))
```

"Invoke-Expression" executes in the same process but waits for termination of b.ps1.

Answer (score 43):

In a.ps1,

```
& .\b.ps1
```

the way you invoke other programs

Answer (score 3):

Use the magic variable $PSScriptRoot to refer to your current directory.
Then call script B with the ampersand ("Call operator"):

```
$script = $PSScriptRoot+"\b.ps1"
& $script
```

If you want to keep the variables from B in scope of A, you can run the script using the Dot sourcing operator:

```
$script = $PSScriptRoot+"\b.ps1"
. $script
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this from a different article but it can apply here:
thanks (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist)

First, if you want to make multiple calls in a single session to a remote machine, first create a PSSession:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
```

Then use that session in all subsequent calls:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -File $filename
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
# Some code
```

}
Then close the session when you're done:

```
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

also if you don't know exactly ware that script will be but know whare your script starts u can do this:

```
$strInst = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter Import-Carbon.ps1 -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select Directory
Invoke-Experssion (start Powershell ($strinst\Import-Carbon.ps1)
```

(thats mine)

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and doesn't address the question.